# Flutter Drive tests crashes on OS pop-ip (e.g. notification consent)

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am using Flutter Drive for integration tests. The tests works well until app shows push notification consent. It seems Flutter Drive doesn't recognise the pop-up by iOS and crashes it there.

```
      takeScreenshot(driver,"screenshots/01.login_screen_initial.png");
      await driver.tap(tfUserId);
      await driver.enterText('100111');
      await driver.tap(tfPassword);
      await driver.enterText('abc');
      takeScreenshot(driver,"screenshots/02.login_screen_before_button_tap.png");
      await driver.tap(loginButton);
```

After this button tap, the app asks for push notification consent. And the following code never gets executed.

```
    takeScreenshot(driver,"screenshots/03.login_screen_just_after_button_tap.png");
    await driver.waitForAbsent(btnHRDirectory,timeout: Duration(seconds: 360));
    takeScreenshot(driver,"screenshots/04.dashboard_screen.png");
```

I get error as :

```
[VERBOSE-2:rasterizer.cc(307)] Last layer tree was null when screenshotting.
```

Detailed error is [here](https://pastebin.com/BLbuM8xk).

Comment: `Flutter Drive doesn't recognise the pop-up by iOS`, does it work on Android ?

Comment: Just found out that the issue was somewhere in script. Fixed and now it works for both iOS and Android. Flutter Drive waits for the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was somewhere in the script. driver.WaitFor along with timeout duration helps. No problem for the pop-up as Flutter Drive waits for the pop-up to vanish.